# PHP routing not including files

Tags: php, apache, url-routing

I tried a simple routing for PHP but I'm getting crazy because it's not fully working...
Hope anyone can help. This is my first try to write an own routing with PHP.

**Problem**

When I request "SERVER-IP/hms/routing/test" it shows content of home.php - ok

When I request "SERVER-IP/hms/routing/shop" it shows 404-error.... - why??
As soon as I'm deleting "shop.php" on server, it shows my index.php with

> Request:/hms/routing/shop 
> URL: /shop

Don't know why it's not loading the files properly...
Any idea why it's not working? :(

**My .htaccess**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /hms/routing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**My index.php**

```
<?php

$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

echo "Request:".$request."<br>";

$url = str_replace("/hms/routing","", $request);

echo "URL: ".$url."<br>";

switch ($url) {
    case "/":
        include "home.php";
        break;
        
    case "/about":
        include "about.php";
        break;
        
    case "/test":
        include "home.php";
        break;
        
    case "/shop":
        include "shop.php";
        break;
        
}
?>
```

Thanks a lot in advance! :)

Comment: I hope your ``shop.php` file exist on the same folder structure as ``index.php`` file? Also, can you trim your ``URL`` before passing it to ``SWITCH`` as there can be some unrequested spaces?

Comment: What's in shop.php? It appears to be including it as otherwise you would see the `echo` from index.php. There may be a redirect or other condition causing the 404 on shop.php. Other suggestions: remove the php closing tag at the last line in index.php and the other include files, as it is known to cause issues. Change `include "shop.php";` in favor of using `require_once` with an absolute path `require_once __DIR__ . '/shop.php';`, to ensure the file exists at the fully qualified path or will emit an error and is only included once, preventing circular references.

Comment: Hi. Yes, all files are in the same folder. I've also addes a `$url = trim($url);` but with no effect.

Comment: I've changed from `include...` to `require_once(__DIR__ . "/shop.php");` but still same issue. I've also removed `?>` from index.php

Comment: If you are not seeing a PHP error when using `require_once` that file does not exist, then index.php is loading shop.php and your issue is being caused by the shop.php script. My other suggestions were code-quality suggestions to improve performance and reduce potential issues. Note: `require`, `include`, etc are not function calls and do not need brackets, using brackets with them causes extra parsing time by the PHP lexer.

Comment: Thanks, I've changed to `require_once "shop.php";`
Can it be some error in my .htaccess? Because the 404-site I get is some default page which is created by my Synology Webserver. Maybe it's an issue with the Rewrite Rules?

Comment: You should favor using absolute paths `__DIR__ . '/shop.php'` with any include file, to prevent PHP from trying to load files from the include path, allow for code portability and slightly improve performance as a result.

Comment: Hm, when I request `http://SERVER-IP/hms/routing/shop.php` it loads shop.php but when I request `http://SERVER-IP/hms/routing/shop` it returns 404. So maybe really an issue with .htaccess!?

Comment: Hm okay. But shop.php only contains one line: `<h1>Welcome to the Shop</h1>`
I have no idea why it's not working... :\
Why does it work with `.../test`?

Comment: I've replaced the line but still same issue :(
Do I need to configure anything on my Server (Synology NAS)?

Comment: The issue is caused by [`Options MultiViews`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/content-negotiation.html) being included in your Apache configuration for your virtual host. "*Using a 'MultiViews' search, where the server does an implicit filename pattern match and chooses from among the results.*" Change in your .htaccess file at the top `Options -MultiViews`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally it worked!
Thanks to Will B., the solution is as follows:

**.htaccess**

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /hms/routing
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [L,QSA]
```

**index.php**

```
<?php

$request = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];

echo "Request:".$request."<br>";

$url = str_replace("/hms/routing","", $request);
$url = trim($url);

echo "URL: ".$url."<br>";
echo "Complete: ". __DIR__ . $url.".php<br>";


switch ($url) {
    case "/":
        require_once __DIR__ . '/home.php';
        break;
        
    case "/about":
        require_once __DIR__ . '/about.php';
        break;
        
    case "/test":
        require_once  __DIR__ . '/home.php';
        break;
        
    case "/shop":
        require_once __DIR__ . '/shop.php';
        break;
        
}
```

I think what finally helped was `Options -MultiViews` in .htaccess

Thanks a lot for help! :)

Comment: Please note for `Options -MultiViews` to work in your `.htaccess` file, that the Apache VirtualHost configuration must be set to `AllowOverride All` or at least `AllowOverride Options=MultiViews`  for the `<Directory>` path of the `DOCUMENT_ROOT`, eg: `<Directory "/hms/routing">AllowOverride All</Directory>`